# Citing Oracle documentations of Java

Tags: technical-writing, citations

How can I properly cite an Oracle's documentation of the usage of certain APIs?

For instance
[HashMap - Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

I need to cite/reference this in my research paper, what is the best way to do it, since there isn't any author.

I need it to be in Harvard style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general format for a reference citation in Harvard style is:

> Last name, First Initial. (Year published). Title. City: Publisher, Page(s).

For a web site, [this guide](http://www.citethisforme.com/harvard-referencing) gives the following format:

> Last name, First initial (Year published). Page title. [online] Website name. Available at: URL [Accessed Day Mo. Year].

If there is no author, you substitute the name of the site:

> Website name, (Year published). *Page title*. [online] Available at: URL [Accessed Day Mo. Year].

(This is different from other styles where you would use something like "____" in place of an author or just omit it.)

For your example, then, the citation would be:

> Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 7 API Specification, (2017). *Interface Map<K,V>*. [online] Available at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html [Accessed Dec 3, 2017].

I didn't find a clearly-authoritative source for Harvard Style; the site I used seems to be pretty popular.